# Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression

Tags: flutter, http, dart, rest, riverpod

I am using Riverpod to fetch Api and display in the app, and my method , "getMovieList()" requires a String, but in the below code I am getting this Error :
"**The instance member 'pageNumber' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expressiondartimplicit_this_reference_in_initializer**"

```
class StateManager {

  final String pageNumber;
  StateManager(this.pageNumber);
  
  static final movieStateFuture = FutureProvider<List<Movie>>((ref) async {
    return ApiSetup.getMovieList(pageNumber); // The error is Here "The instance member 'pageNumber' can't be accessed in an initializer."

  });
}
```

```
class ApiSetup {
  static List<Movie> parsePhotos(String responseBody) {
    List<Movie> listMovies = [];
    for (var mov in jsonDecode(responseBody)['results']) {
      final movie = Movie.fromJson(mov);
      listMovies.add(movie);
    }
    return listMovies;
  }

  static Future<List<Movie>> getMovieList(String pageNum) async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=${Constants.apiKey}&language=en-US&page=$pageNum"));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
    } else {
      print("Error here");
    }
    throw Exception("Some Random Error");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not refer a **non static** member from inside a `static` method. Your `pageNumber` is an attribute that belongs to the instance/object of `StateManager` whereas static methods belongs to the class.

If you want to use pageNumber while accessing the future try using `family` provider instead:

```dart
static final movieStateFuture = FutureProvider.family<List<Movie>,int>( //<-- Add '.family' modifer and 'datatype' of the argument
  (ref, pageNum) async { //<-- Second argument to create method is the parameter you pass
    return ApiSetup.getMovieList(pageNum);
  }
);
```

Now while calling `movieStateFuture`, pass in the argument like this:

```dart
watch(movieStateFuture(/*PAGE_NUMBER_HERE*/));
```